# How do I unit test a Servlet Filter with jUnit?

Tags: java, junit

Implemented `doFilter()`. How to properly cover Filter with jUnit ?

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws java.io.IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException
{
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    String currentURL = request.getRequestURI();

    if (!currentURL.equals("/maintenance.jsp") && modeService.getOnline())
    {
        response.sendRedirect("/maintenance.jsp");
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

Comment: You obviously have a web application. JUnit by itself doesn't handle the web, but there are other tools. How do you check your servlets for example?

Comment: you mean to use GUI testing ?

Answer (score 43):

`ServletRequest`, `ServletResponse` and `FilterChain` are all interfaces, so you can easily create test stubs for them, either by hand or using a mocking framework.

Make the mock objects configurable so that you can prepare a canned response to `getRequestURI()` and so that you can query the ServletResponse to assert that sendRedirect has been invoked.

Inject a mock ModeService.

Invoke doFilter passing the mock ServletRequest, ServletResponse and FilterChain as its parameters.

```
@Test
public void testSomethingAboutDoFilter() {
    MyFilter filterUnderTest = new MyFilter();
    filterUnderTest.setModeService(new MockModeService(ModeService.ONLINE));
    MockFilterChain mockChain = new MockFilterChain();
    MockServletRequest req = new MockServletRequest("/maintenance.jsp");
    MockServletResponse rsp = new MockServletResponse();

    filterUnderTest.doFilter(req, rsp, mockChain);

    assertEquals("/maintenance.jsp",rsp.getLastRedirect());
}
```

In practice you'll want to move the setup into an @Before `setUp()` method, and write more @Test methods to cover every possible execution path.

... and you'd probably use a mocking framework like JMock or Mockito to create mocks, rather than the hypothetical `MockModeService` etc. I've used here.

This is a *unit testing* approach, as opposed to an integration test. You are only exercising the unit under test (and the test code).

Comment: +1. FYI: You don't inject the `FilterChain` instance — it's a parameter of the doFilter method. I've changed the example to reflect that.

Comment: Only now it is `MockHttpServletRequest` and `MockHttpServletResponse`.

Answer (score 27):

If you are using Spring then it has own mocks:

- org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain
- org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest
- org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse

For example, you can add headers and set test Uri.

So your test can be smth like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TokenAuthenticationFilterTest {

    private static final String token = "260bce87-6be9-4897-add7-b3b675952538";
    private static final String testUri = "/testUri";

    @Mock
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @InjectMocks
    private TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter();

    @Test
    public void testDoFilterInternalPositiveScenarioWhenTokenIsInHeader() throws ServletException, IOException {
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        request.addHeader(TOKEN, token);
        request.setRequestURI(testUri);
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        MockFilterChain filterChain = new MockFilterChain();
        when(securityService.doesExistToken(token)).thenReturn(true);
        tokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    }
}
```

Comment: for junit5-jupiter, here are some of the magic items : import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyCustomConfigObj.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyCustomConfigObj.class)
public class MyCustomConfigObjTest { }

Answer (score 23):

You could use a mocking framework in order to mock the above `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse` and `FilterChain` objects and their behavior. Depending on the framework, you have certain functionality in order to verify if during the execution of the code correct actions on the mocked objects where taken.

For example when using the **Mockito** mock framework, the provided `doFilter()` method could be JUnit tested using below test case:

```
@Test
public void testDoFilter() throws IOException, ServletException {
    // create the objects to be mocked
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    FilterChain filterChain = mock(FilterChain.class);
    // mock the getRequestURI() response
    when(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()).thenReturn("/otherurl.jsp");

    MaintenanceFilter maintenanceFilter = new MaintenanceFilter();
    maintenanceFilter.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse,
            filterChain);

    // verify if a sendRedirect() was performed with the expected value
    verify(httpServletResponse).sendRedirect("/maintenance.jsp");
}
```

Comment: This is a nice example and the best way to do it (IMO), but qualifying the static methods with Mockito and maybe even showing the imports to clarify for newbies would make it better.

Comment: My kingdom for imports and groupid/artifactid(s).