# how to fetch response from requestContext.abortwith() method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

```
Class Permission implements ContainerRequestContext
{

    @context
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException 
    {
        String Path=servletRequest.getPathInfo;

        int id=containerRequestContext.getId;

        if(id==null){
            containerRequestContext.abortWith(new ServerResponse(ExceptionUtil.getErrorMessageObject(...),errorCode,new Header<Object>()));
        }
    }
}
```

For the Testing purpose,

How to fetch the `errorCode` set inside the `ServerResponse` object when we are setting the id=null.

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    class Test {

  @InjectMocks
  private Permission permission;
  @Mock
  private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
  @Mock
  private ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext;

  @Test
  public void test()
  {
      when(servletRequest.getPathInfo()).thenReturn("/getid");
      when(containerRequestContext.getId()).thenReturn(null);
      permission.filter(containerRequestContext);

      Response r = //Need the code. How to get the Response that i have set on permission class when id=null so that i can fetch the errorCode from that.
  //With that erroCode i can write my test methods.
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please include your current attempt at testing this. The answer depends on your testing setup. Here's [an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451917/how-do-i-unit-test-a-servlet-filter-with-junit).

Comment: Added the Test Class and the Description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is an `ArgumentCaptor`:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Response> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Response.class);
verify(containerRequestContext).abortWith( argumentCaptor.capture() );
```

This checks if the method `abortWith` has been called exactly once (once being the default for `verify`) and stores the argument it has been called with in the `ArgumentCaptor` from which you can get it via...

```
Response response = argumentCaptor.getValue();
```

For further details see the [JavaDoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.11.0/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html).

Of course, there are other ways (for example, you could use an `Answer`) but they are not as easy.