# How to Mock with MockHttpSession and Junit

Tags: spring, junit, spring-security, mockito

Looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451917/how-do-i-unit-test-a-servlet-filter-with-junit) where **@slim** gave a solution close to what I am asking about. I am trying to write unit test on the class below. I am pulling out the sessionId. (**look for String sessId inside doFilterInternal method**)

```
@Component
public class AppLoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private AppLoggingMDCService mdcService;

    @Inject
    public AppLoggingFilter(AppLoggingMDCService appLoggingMDCService) {
        Assert.notNull(appLoggingMDCService, "AppLoggingMDCService must not be null");
        this.mdcService = appLoggingMDCService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {   

        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        String sessId = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(request.getSession().getId());

        if (principal != null) {
            String userId = principal.getName();
            mdcService.put(AppLoggingMDCService.LOG_KEY_USER_ID, userId);
        }
        mdcService.put(AppLoggingMDCService.LOG_KEY_SESSION_ID, sessId);
        try {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {

        mdcService.removeAll();
    }
}
```

Naturally the test below is failing because I don't have a valid session. Obviously I am getting a null-pointer-exception whenever i call **filter.doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);**. In the test class, the "mock-session" is not set up and has no ID. In my unit test I have this.

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ActiveProfiles(value = {"test"})
    public class AppLoggingFilterUnitTest {

        @Mock
        AppLoggingMDCService mdcService;

        @Mock
        MockHttpServletRequest request;

        @Mock
        MockHttpServletResponse response;

        @Mock
        MockFilterChain filterChain;

        @Mock
        MockHttpSession session; 

        @InjectMocks
        AppLoggingFilter filter;

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            request.setSession(session);
        }

        @Test
        public void testCustomerIdHasBeenLogged() throws Exception {
            String customerId = "1234";
            when(request.getHeader(AuthorizationConstants.CUSTOMER_KEY)).thenReturn(customerId);
            filter.doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);
            verify(mdcService, times(1)).put(AppLoggingMDCService.LOG_KEY_CUST_ID,customerId);
        }
  }
```

So coming back to my question, how do simulate as valid mocked "MockHttpSession" so my others tests don't fail?

**UPDATE**
So I added the session into my test class like this. In my setup method is where I said to return the "Mocked" session. The test passes only when I call
**`String sessId = request.getSession().getId();`**. if I try to do the DigestUtils.sha256Hex like 
`String sessId = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(request.getSession().getId());` ,all tests fail due to a null-pointer. I am not sure why. Mocking DigestUtils doesn't make much sense.

```
@Mock
AppLoggingMDCService mdcService;

@Mock
HttpServletRequest request;

@Mock
HttpServletResponse response;

@Mock
FilterChain filterChain;

@Mock
HttpSession session; 

@InjectMocks
AppLoggingFilter filter;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(this.session);
}
```

Comment: in the code you have `request.getSession()` you have not mocked this. that is the issue. instead of doing a setsession on the request object, mock the getsession call

Comment: Your test is way to complex. The `MockHttpSession` is meant to be instantiated by yourself NOT mocked by mockito (that goes for all the `Mock*` related classes).

Comment: @pvpkiran I used your suggestion and mocked the session as seen in my UPDATE above. However I am still having test-failures as descripbed in my UPDATE, due to a null-pointer. I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing to much in your test and it is way to complex. Remove the runner, remove Mockito for the `Mock*` as those need to be instantiated not mocked.

```java
public class AppLoggingFilterUnitTest {

    @Mock
    private AppLoggingMDCService mdcService;

    @InjectMocks
    private AppLoggingFilter filter;

    private MockHttpServletRequest request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    private MockFilterChain filterChain = new MockFilterChain();


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        this.request.addHeader(AuthorizationConstants.CUSTOMER_KEY, "1234"); 
    }

    @Test
    public void testCustomerIdHasBeenLogged() throws Exception {
        filter.doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);
        verify(mdcService, times(1)).put(AppLoggingMDCService.LOG_KEY_CUST_ID,customerId);
    }
}
```

With the creating of the mocks for the `Mock*` classes you basically defeated the purpose of those classes.